# Open and closing a program. Shell Script

Tags: shell, debian

REALLY new to this stuff, sorry.

So I want a shell script to open a program, wait 45 minutes, close it, and then do it all again. I want to do this because I am running an iMacros Script for a long period of time and if Firefox is not constantly restarted, memory leaks start to happen.

Anyway heres my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
while :
do
'/usr/lib64/iceweasel/iceweasel imacros://run/?m=macro.iim' &
sleep 5
'/usr/lib64/iceweasel/iceweasel imacros://run/?m=macro.iim' &
sleep 2700
killall firefox-bin
done
```

When I open it using "sh /root/whatever.sh" I get this error:
"line 12: syntax error near unexpected token 'done'"
"line 12: done"

Can anyone help? thanks!

edit: oh yeah, for anyone who isnt familiar to iMacros scripting, running the macro twice after 5 seconds is needed because firefox is not properly loaded during this time

Comment: your script hasn't 12 lines... maybe post the real one?

Comment: oh the other lines were just comments i made at the top

Comment: Well, as is, there's no syntax error associated with 'done'.   We probably would need to see your comments to see if they are generating a syntax error.  This line: '/usr/lib64/iceweasel/iceweasel imacros://run/?m=macro.iim' &  
is incorrect.  Should be: '/usr/lib64/iceweasel/iceweasel' 'imacros://run/?m=macro.iim' &

Comment: Sounds like a script with CRLF microsoft line endings where the `do` is actually `do<CR>`, so the shell doesn't expect a `done` as it has not seen a (proper) `do`. Quoting `'/usr/lib64/iceweasel/iceweasel imacros://run/?m=macro.iim'` doesn't make sense as I don't expect you'd have a command called `iceweasel imacros://run/?m=macro.iim` in `/usr/lib64/iceweasel`